# State is not updating in React js for Google maps

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update my state with an object which is received from the JSON. Here I am receiving {lat, lng} from JSON. But those values are not updating in the state.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyMap from "./mymap";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      place: "Hyderabad Telagnana",
      latlng: null
    };
  }

  zipCode = postalCodes => {
    this.setState({ latlng: postalCodes });
  };

  render() {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${this.state.place}&key=AIzaSyB6w_WDy6psJ5HPX15Me1-oE&libraries=places`
      )
      .then(res => {
        const postalCodes = res.data.results[0].geometry.location;
        this.zipCode(postalCodes);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error");
      });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MyMap lat={this.state.latlng.lat} lng={this.state.latlng.lng} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? You most likely want to move you axios request to `componentDidMount` instead of having it run on every render, and since `this.state.latlng` is `null` at first `this.state.latlng.lat` will give you an error.

Comment: I am getting 'Cannot read property 'lat' of null' error, But I tried to update my state.

Answer (score 2):

Having the axios request in your render method will make it run on every render, and since `this.state.latlng` is `null` at first `this.state.latlng.lat` will give you an error.

You could instead move the axios request to `componentDidMount`, and not render anything until the `latlng` object has been set in your state.

**Example**

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      place: "Hyderabad Telagnana",
      latlng: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${this.state.place}&key=AIzaSyB6w_WDy6psJ5HPX15Me1-oE&libraries=places`
      )
      .then(res => {
        const postalCodes = res.data.results[0].geometry.location;
        this.setState({ latlng: postalCodes });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { latlng } = this.state;

    if (latlng === null) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MyMap lat={this.state.latlng.lat} lng={this.state.latlng.lng} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just about to post the same thing. You beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still, I am getting following error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
    at App.js:21

Comment: @BhavaniRaju You're welcome. I see. Then the response data might not look as expected, or the `results` array might be empty?

Comment: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: an object with keys {lat, lng}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. Now i am getting the above error.

Comment: @BhavaniRaju Sounds like an issue with data still, or the implementation of `MyMap`.

Comment: Above I posted Mymap.js file as well. Could you please look into that?

Comment: @BhavaniRaju I don't think you should remove your `App` from the question, and please try and format your code as it's pretty hard to read.

Comment: If I would not have removed app.js. It's saying that 'you have more code'. So I couldn't post MyMap.js file.

Comment: @BhavaniRaju Please consider reverting to your previous edit and create another question as it's not good Stack Overflow practice to rewrite the question, and especially not after it has been answered.

Comment: My apologies :)

Comment: const google = window.google;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
            zoom: 13,
            center: this.props
        });      I passed the state like in the MyMap component.